# Trig problem about equation of a line perpendicular to a line from the origin.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Why is the slope of the red line $= -\cot(\theta)$?

I tried to draw it and find out that it is really $= -\cot(\theta)$, but how can we show it algebraically by using formula and other stuff not only geometric proof?

And why does the line intersect the $y$-axis at $\dfrac{d}{\sin(\theta)}$??? How can we get this one?

I'm a newbie. Please give me step by step and detail explanation. Thank you. ^^

[image]

This photo is from this forum: https://discussions.udacity.com/t/how-to-get-the-hough-transform-formula/176747/4

It's about Hough Transform in computer vision.

Answer (score 3):

the product of slopes of two perpendicular lines slope is $-1$
id est $(m_1\cdot m_2=-1) $

So, the slope of the perpendicular line
$$\frac{-1}{\tan(\theta)}=-\cot(\theta)$$
The other distance is basically simple trigonometry..
Note that the angle adjacent to $\theta$
 is $$90^\circ - \theta$$
So the angle at which it touches y-axis is $\theta$

Can you figure it now?
Here is the figure

[image]

Comment: OMG amazing answer, thank you very much for your help ^^ Can you please also add a little bit of explanation about why the product of slopes of two perpendicular lines slope is -1?